# How to prevent scanning for solutions in Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 takes a long time to open.  This is mainly because we have allot of solutions in our team project (we use TFS).  Does anyone know of a way to disable it from searching for solutions?  I know where my solutions are I don't need the Team Explorer to give me a list.

Comment: switch your workspace, to server workspace to stop scanning, or clean out your workspace to reduce scanning times

Comment: This is a way bigger problem on Virtual Machines that many uses to develop. Takes several minutes before you can do anything after opening Visual Studio. Take a look at this feedback at MS: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813904/when-connecting-to-tfs-scanning-for-solutions-operation-takes-a-long-time-and-hangs-the-application

Comment: I have a server workspace (I don't like local workspaces), yet Visual Studio still scans for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I started using VS 2013 earlier this year and recently noticed it pausing on startup for a couple minutes while scanning for solutions. While waiting this last time I thought I'd search for how to turn that "feature" off and ran across this and some other threads.

The comment about Workspaces caught my attention. I checked back in Team Explorer (which by then had finished scanning) and noticed a dropdown list for Workspaces. It showed the normal one I use, plus a couple others that were created automatically by a tool we use (SQL Source Control, by Red Gate, which automatically establishes a link between a database and a location in TFS to keep a script representation of all you databases objects in your Source Control system, for which it needs its own Workspaces on your machine to manage) which are relatively small and... contain no .sln files.

So I selected one of the SQL Source Control Workspaces from the list and it started a new scan, this one taking only about 1 second, finding nothing. :)

Then I checked my workspaces in Source Control Explorer and my normal Workspace was still selected with the others still there for Red Gate, too.

Finally I closed and reopened VS. This time the SQL Source Control Workspace was still selected and the scan finished in a snap again. Works almost as good as having it disabled.

If you only have one Workspace, (most people would, I think), I think you could create a "dummy" Workspace for some empty or meaningless folder on your machine and let Team Explorer scan that one every time you start up, instead.

CAUTION: Just don't forget and get confused and blame me if somehow you accidently get switched to that "dummy" and suddenly find none of your files in Source Control appear to be downloaded. Before you download them again into the dummy folder, check that the correct Workspace is selected